# Connect amplify to github enterprise

Tags: github, aws-amplify

We are trying to create an AWS amplify app. For CI/CD we want to integrate it with Github. I understand amplify has a way to add a Github account(personal with username and password), but I am not able to find a way to add a Github Enterprise account( that doesn't have such username and password credentials).

Is there a way to add Github enterprise to amplify, like how Codebuild allows to connect.

Answer (score 0):

A GHE (GitHub Enterprise) server does [support GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions#pricing-details)

So check first if activating an action like [amplify-cli-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/amplify-cli-action) or (depending on what you want to do) [`amplify-preview-actions`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/amplify-preview-actions) would help in your case.

In term of credentials, those actions [would need](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/amplify-cli-action#aws-credentials-controlling-access-with-iam):

> 1. Navigate to AWS Identity and Access Management console
> 2. Under `Users -> Add New User`. Fill in the user `name(GithubCI)` and set `Programmatic Access` for `Access type`.
> 3. In permissions, select `Create a new group`, in a dropdown select `Create policy`.
> 4. In a policy creation menu, select `JSON` tab and fill it with a next policy statement, then hit review and save